# ExtJS - Preventing click/enter editing in grid with roweditor

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs-mvc

I want to have a dedicated edit toolbar button on my grid and use double-click/Enter key for other purpose.

Can I somehow change the click/enter-to-edit behavior of the row-editor plugin without hacking away at its' internals? From a glance on the code it seems pretty rigid, but I thought maybe someone already had this problem and has a creative solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like this works, if anyone got a better idea, I'm open to suggestions

```
plugins: [
    Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.RowEditing', {
        startEditByClick: function (){},
        onEnterKey: function (){}
    })
],
```

Comment: Would you think you can access "onEnterKey" in Plugin , In Extjs 4.2 It looks like a private function "Ext.grid.plugin.Editing" not "Ext.grid.plugin.RowEditing".
It doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

In ExtJs 4.2 this solution don't work. You should override the `onCellClick` method like you posted above:

```
plugins: [
    Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.RowEditing', {
        onCellClick: function (){}            
    })
]
```

This works for me.